# The choice of preposition "for" vs "to" with "criterion"

Tags: prepositions

I came across the following sentence while reading a book.

> An alternative criterion **for** classifying networks is by scale.

I wonder if **for** can be replaced by **to**, as below.

> An alternative criterion **to classify** networks is by scale.

Is the new sentence grammatical and idiomatic? Do they have exactly the same meaning?

I'd appreciate an in depth answer or a link to such an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example is normal. I do not find your second example natural: I think it is conflating two different constructions.

#### Complement of "criterion"

The noun *criterion* makes no sense unless the distinction it is making is defined in some way: that distinction is naturally conveyed by a complement using "for":

> A criterion for classifying networks.

Like most complements, the target of the distinction can often be omitted, if it has already been mentioned, or is obvious:

> What criterion are you using?

But without something external to the discourse, it is incoherent to leave it out:

> Hello, what do you want? I want a criterion.

Sometimes we can supply the context by a modifier:

> Can you use the equality criterion?

---

#### "To" purpose clause

Separately, there is a (general) use of a "to" phrase to express purpose:

> I'm taking that book to read it on the bus.

"to read it on the bus" is not syntactically connected to "that book", but is an adjunct of the verb "taking".

In the same way, if we are talking about doing something with a criterion (using it, choosing one, refining one, etc) we can also use a "to" purpose clause:

> I'm using an alternative criterion to classify networks.

So "to classify ... " is not a complement of "criterion", but an adjunct to "using".

However, in your second example, I don't find that there is anywhere for the "to" phrase to attach. While I would understand it, it feels strange to me.

---

#### Corpus search

I searched the NoW corpus for instances of "criterion for VERB-ing", and got 1320.

Then I searched for  "criterion to VERB", and at first was surprised to find that there were nearly half as many: 631; I expected far fewer.

However, on inspection, nearly all of the latter are cases where the "to" phrase does not define the criterion, such as:

> The graph below uses the installed Windows version as the criterion to determine which devices are home and which are corporate users.

There are only a few examples with the same structure as your second one, such as:

> If you're tracking monetary return on investment (ROI) as the sole criterion to determine if your marketing programs are working,

Comment: I just read this answer again and noticed that I forgot to thank you. So thank you for this great answer.

While we're at it, could you explain what the NoW corpus is and how to use it?

Comment: It's one of a load of corpora available at https://www.english-corpora.org/ , @piotrekg2. They're free to use (but if you use them a lot, it starts nagging you to take a paid subscription).

Answer (score 0):

The use of "for" in a sentence usually warrants the inclusion of an "ing" in the following verb. "to" uses the verb in its original form. And yes, both sentences are grammatically correct and have the same exact meaning.